# Partially typed generic objects when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to get fields through reflection, for example private field:

```
private Dictionary<string, SourceVoicePool> m_voiceHudPools;
```

But the class `SourceVoicePool` is private co I cannot use it's type and I cannot use type `Dictionary<string, SourceVoicePool>` in my code.

I would like to at least use for example this kind of typing:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

So that I can at least operate the dictionary. I am only able to get this property typed as `object` and then I have to use reflection to access dictionary fields and methods even though I know Dictionary class.

Can his be done better?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you've a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you don't have to use reflection for all operations related to that dictionary. What are the values of this dict? Do you try to memorize `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`-instances to get or set there values?

Comment: @Sebastian The problem as I understand it is that the value part of the dictionary is a private type.

Comment: Yes, it is as @DiplomacyNotWar said.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar That's clear. But what's the problem with that? That's okay. _and then I have to use reflection to access dictionary fields and methods_ NO! All the dictionary properties and methods are still available. That is the point that I don't understand.

Comment: And how do you do it? I get this field through reflection, typed as object. How do I get it typed as a Dictionary<>? What will be the type of it's value?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann: with a `TValue` that's private it's basically impossible to do anything with it that doesn't involve reflection at all stages. Even `dynamic`, which would otherwise be ideal for this job, will be of no help because the runtime binder respects type visibility.

Comment: @K.H. `object` as you declared it already.

Comment: Compiler won't let you, try it yourself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` classes implement the non-generic interface [IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary). If the operations in this interface are enough for your use case, use it.

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = myObj.GetType().GetField("m_voiceHudPools",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
IDictionary dict = (IDictionary)fieldInfo.GetValue(myObj, null);
object myValue = dict["myKey"];
```

Of course, to access the properties and method of the value object, you again have to use reflection.

Comment: Not the best, but still better than having result typed as object. Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually this is probably as good as it gets. Combined with `public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)` used on `Keys` or `Values`, this makes it very usable :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given a class with private members and types

```
public class A
{
    private class B
    { public int C; }

    private Dictionary<string, B> D = new Dictionary<string, B>();
}
```

you can use reflection to access the type parameters of the dictionary and then call a generic method with those type parameters applied:

```
class Inspect
{
    public static void Reflect()
    {
        var a = new A();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = a.GetType().GetField("D",
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var dictionary = fieldInfo.GetValue(a);
        var dictionaryType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
        var method = DoStuff<int,int>;
        var methodInfo = method.GetMethodInfo();
        var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        var typedMethodInfo = genericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(dictionaryType.GenericTypeArguments);
        typedMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { dictionary });
    }

    public static void DoStuff<T1,T2>(Dictionary<T1,T2> dictionary)
    {
        IEnumerable<T2> a = dictionary.Values;
    }
}
```

In the method DoStuff you now have full access to the types used for the dictionary.

Comment: That's a clever idea, but how would you access e.g. the `C` member in the DoStuff method? I don't see how this can be possible.

Comment: @KlausGütter No, you cannot access internal features of B without further use of reflection, but you do have access to all features of Dictionary, which seems to be the scope of your original question.

Comment: @KlausGütter With reflection, it's easy: `var cField = typeof(T2).GetField("C"); var c = cField.GetValue(a.First());` (assuming the dictionary is not empty).